# No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner.
I'm in trouble because I can't settle an error.

**error message**

No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home"

Rails.root: /home/ec2-user/environment/sample_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
Helper    HTTP Verb    Path    Controller#Action 
root_path    GET    /    static_pages#home
help_path    GET    /help(.:format)    static_pages#help
about_path    GET    /about(.:format)    static_pages#about
contact_path    GET    /contact(.:format)    static_pages#contact
```

sample_app/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root 'static_pages#home'
 get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
 get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
 get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

layout/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application',
'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container">
<%= yield %>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

layout/home.html.erb

```
<div class="center jumbotron">
<h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

<h2>
This is the home page for the
<a href="https://railstutorial.jp/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
sample application.
</h2>

<%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>

<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"),
'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

Comment: Make sure `controllers/static_pages_controller.rb` exist, also `views/static_pages/home.html.erb`. And just for sure restart server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, from your post, that your `home.html.erb` template file is in the wrong place.  There should be a folder called `static_pages` inside `app/views`.  So inside `app/views/static_pages/` is where your `home.html.erb` file should be.  Your code says it is inside the `layouts` folder.  Move it and it will work.

So, specifically, either create the folder `static_pages` (if it does not exist) or move you home.html.erb file into the `app/views/static_pages/` folder.

Just and FYI, if your other views (contact, about, etc) are in the `layout` folder move them into `static_pages` too.  But leave the layout file in there.

Since you are a beginner I'll explain this a little more.  When you set your routes you are telling rails where to find the files.  So when you write something like  `get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help` what you telling rails is when the URL `/help` is viewed serve up the file `help.html.erb` in the `static_pages` folder and it knows to look inside the `app/views` folder by configuration.  If you wanted to keep `home.html.erb` where it is, you could just change you routes to `root 'layouts#home'` and it should work, but since the view file is not a layout file that would not be the best solution.  Hope this helps.

Comment: *When you set your routes you are telling rails where to find the files* - According to the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), *The Rails router recognizes URLs and dispatches them to a controller's action, or to a Rack application.* So, defining routes isn't really about "telling rails where to find the files".

Comment: @jvillian Well, if you write something else, it looks somewhere else doesn't it?  So when you write in the routes file, you ARE telling it where to find the files.  Not really interested in getting in a worthless, waste of time debate about it so If you want to provide a better explanation, please feel free to post an answer.  What I wrote is how I perceive it working, from my understanding,  what you write in the `routes.rb` file determines where rails will look for the files.

Comment: The comment was offered in the spirit of ensuring that the answers on SO are as accurate and precise as possible.